# Javascript simple printing passing parameters

Tags: javascript

I am expecting to print values of passing parameters in below code. But it prints [Object Event].

I am new to presentation development. What Am I missing here.

```
 <body onload("initialize('-33.873651000000000000','151.206889600000070000')")>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src=""></script>

 <script>
function initialize(longitude,latitude){
 alert(longitude)
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body tag needs to be placed within the html tag. Also use onload=""

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src=""></script>

 <script>
function initialize(longitude,latitude){
 alert(longitude)
 }
</script>
   </head>

   <body onload= "initialize('-33.873651000000000000','151.206889600000070000')")>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the tags order in your Html code:
A basic HTML structure is as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>...</body>
</html>
```

Regarding to your question, you need to use the **onload** attribute with the correct format:

```
onload = "[javascript code here]"
```

So you'll have this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function initialize(longitude, latitude){
         alert(longitude);
       }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload = "javascript:initialize('-33.87651000000000000','151.206889600000070000');">
  </body>
<html>
```